# Unable to get the PageLayout for a PublishingWeb using CSOM. Error "The object is not associated with an object identity"

Tags: development, csom, publishing-site, publishing-page

I am working on a console application which uses CSOM to integrate with SharePoint online. and i want to create a publishing page, so i wrote this code, to get the PageLayout and create a new Publishing page, based on the values of other page:-

```
File tempWikiPage = context.Site.RootWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(scurl4 + tempItemTitle + ".aspx");
context.Load(tempWikiPage,items => items.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
List publishingLayouts = context.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery");
CamlQuery camlQuery4 = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery4.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
"<Value Type='String'>Basic Page</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";

ListItemCollection allItems = publishingLayouts.GetItems(camlQuery4);
context.Load(allItems,
items => items.Include(
item => item["Title"]
));

context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem layout = allItems.FirstOrDefault();
PublishingPageInformation publishingPageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
publishingPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = layout;
PublishingPage pPage = pWeb.AddPublishingPage(publishingPageInfo);
ListItem newpage = pPage.ListItem;
newpage["Title"] = newPageName;
newpage["PublishingPageContent"] = r;
newpage["Standard"] = tempWikiPage.ListItemAllFields["Standard"];
```

now i am facing these 2 issues:-

1. the `layout` will be null.
2. once the code reaches  `newpage["Standard"] = tempWikiPage.ListItemAllFields["Standard"];` i got this exception:-

> The object is not associated with an object identity or the object
>   identity is invalid.
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException was caught
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=The object is not associated with an
>   object identity or the object identity is invalid.
>   Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DataConvert.WriteValueToXmlElement(XmlWriter
>   writer, Object objValue, SerializationContext serializationContext)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientActionInvokeMethod.WriteToXmlPrivate(XmlWriter
>   writer, SerializationContext serializationContext)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientActionInvokeMethod..ctor(ClientObject
>   obj, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem.SetFieldValue(String fieldName, Object value)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem.set_Item(String fieldName, Object value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check if the exists page ServerRelativeUrl is right, and make sure the "Standard" field exists in the Pages library.

The following code for your reference.

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
string userName = "test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "xxx";
string newPageName = "new1227.aspx";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = credential;
    Web webSite = context.Web;
    context.Load(webSite);
    PublishingWeb web = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(context, webSite);
    context.Load(web);
    if (web != null)
    {

        // Get Pages Library
        List pages = context.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
        ListItemCollection existingPages = pages.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
        context.Load(existingPages, items => items.Include(item => item.DisplayName).Where(obj => obj.DisplayName == newPageName));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        // Check if page already exists
        if (existingPages != null && existingPages.Count > 0)
        {
            // Page already exists
        }
        else
        {

            // Get Publishing Page Layouts
            List publishingLayouts = context.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
            "<Value Type='Text'>Basic Page</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection allItems = publishingLayouts.GetItems(camlQuery);                       
            context.Load(allItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem layout = allItems.FirstOrDefault();                         

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File tempWikiPage = context.Site.RootWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/team/Pages/EWikiPage.aspx");
            context.Load(tempWikiPage, items => items.ListItemAllFields);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            TaxonomyFieldValueCollection taxFieldValueColl = tempWikiPage.ListItemAllFields["Standard"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
            // Loop through all the taxonomy field values
            string termValueString = string.Empty;
            foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue tv in taxFieldValueColl)
            {                            
                // Display the taxonomy field value
                termValueString += tv.WssId + ";#" + tv.Label + "|" + tv.TermGuid + ";#";    
            }
            termValueString = termValueString.TrimEnd(";#".ToCharArray());

            // Create a publishing page
            PublishingPageInformation publishingPageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
            publishingPageInfo.Name = newPageName;
            publishingPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = layout;
            PublishingPage pPage = web.AddPublishingPage(publishingPageInfo);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newpage = pPage.ListItem;
            newpage["Title"] = newPageName;
            newpage["PublishingPageContent"] = "Test";
            newpage["Standard"] = termValueString;
            newpage.Update();
            newpage.File.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
            newpage.File.Publish(string.Empty);
            newpage.File.Approve(string.Empty);
            context.Load(newpage);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @L thanks your code was able to retirve the layout.. but i am still not able to get the Standard field for the `tempWikipage` seems `items => items.ListItemAllFields` will not load all properties..

Comment: keeping in mind that the Standard is a managed metadata column which allow multiple values..

Comment: Check my updated code in reply above.

Comment: thanks worked well..

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your CAML query. Try using `Text` instead of `String`.

So this:

```
camlQuery4.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
"<Value Type='String'>Basic Page</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
```

Should become:

```
camlQuery4.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
"<Value Type='Text'>Basic Page</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
```

I'm not sure for the second error, but try checking if `tempWikiPage.ListItemAllFields["Standard"]` exists before setting it to the `newPage["Standard"]`.

Comment: this did not fix the issue and the layout is still null..